# Passing value to placeholder in spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have generated a client interface from api specs

```
@FeignClient(
    name = "${testController.name:testController}",
    url = "${testController.url:https://api.dev.foo}",
    configuration = {ClientConfiguration.class}
)
public interface TetsControllerApiClient extends TestControllerApi {
}
```

How can I override the `name`, or `url` properties on it? Will appreciate an help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override them in your application.properties file in your project

```
testController.name = "myController"
testController.url = "some url"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is loaded from the properties file (either `application.yml` or `application.properties`).

The notation `${testController.name:testController}` is a Spring expression language and says the following:

- Load `testController.name` and read its value from the properties.
- If it is not found, use `testController` as a default value instead.

The `application.properties` file shall look like:

```
testController.name=myTestController
```

To **override** the value you can use Spring profiles. File `application-local-dev.properties` and starting the application with the `local-dev` profile.

Comment: This worked, added it in the properties like yours and the other answer mentioned.